# How to describe the type of a dictionary in typescript efficiently?

Tags: typescript

How to describe the type of a dictionary in typescript more efficient, than the solution below?

```
type DictEntry = { [key: string]: string }
type UploadDict = { [key: string]: DictEntry }

const UPLOAD_TYPE_DICT: UploadDict = {
  JPG: {
    label: "jpg",
    type: "image/jpeg",
  },
  PNG: {
    label: "png",
    type: "image/png",
  },
}
```

Comment: More efficiently *how*? Would inlining `DictEntry` into `UploadDict` be "more efficient"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a cleaner syntax with *more efficiently* use [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

```js
type DictEntry = Record<string, string>
type UploadDict = Record<string, DictEntry>

const UPLOAD_TYPE_DICT: UploadDict = {
  JPG: {
    label: "jpg",
    type: "image/jpeg",
  },
  PNG: {
    label: "png",
    type: "image/png",
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see some type patterns from your example, so I'd propose using `enum` to keep file types and using `DictEntry` to keep `label` and `type` as strongly-typed properties

You can check the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYglgG2AFQJ4AdhQN4CgpQBSACgOIA0%20UxAcqbgL664AuGWAInAMYsCiIFgCdUUALw4oCAIYAjYAgBcUAM7C4IAObkobTMrVCNmqEz1YAqugQB7aQBMuvcZIDaAaSgaoAa2CobADNddiDYRBR2AF1lJ35BEVNmbhsQNSgLYgAZAHkAQQ4AfWQATWI%20Qo4ASQBhZGUrWwc4lzwCElJlNoIpOQVlACIAK3RNAcoekP0oAbgIaU1gAHoR4DGJ0w3aTpwqAhl5JRn0LXG9qeBBuYXlk-WqBkoGIA)

```
enum FileType {
  JPG,
  PNG
}

type DictEntry = { label: string, type: string }
type UploadDict = { [K in keyof typeof FileType]: DictEntry }

const UPLOAD_TYPE_DICT: UploadDict = {
  JPG: {
    label: "jpg",
    type: "image/jpeg",
  },
  PNG: {
    label: "png",
    type: "image/png",
  },
}
```